# Is there a library function in ATS for randomly permuting a list?

Tags: ats

Given a linear list, is there a library function in ATS that shuffles the list randomly to produce a permutation of it:

```
fun{a:t@ype}
list_vt_permute{n:int}(xs: list_vt(a, n)): list_vt(a, n)
```

If possible, I would prefer an implementation of `list_vt_permute` that does not call malloc/free.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is such a function declared in prelude/list_vt.sats, which is based on the function `array_permute` declared in prelude/array.sats.

Note that `list_vt_permute` calls `list_vt_permute$randint` for generating random numbers, and it essentially implements the Fisher-Yates algorithm to perform random shuffling. The function `list_vt_permute` is O(n)-time and it does need to allocate memory for temporary use.

As for a version of `list_vt_permute` that does not need malloc/free, it can be implemented like mergesort, taking O(n*log(n))-time to finish.